Enable A shortcut to add an answer on one's own question

Feature request: enable A shortcut to add an answer on one's own question.
Current behavior: the A shortcut only works on other people's questions.


Seems the reason is that the text area for the answer is not visible immediately. The shortcut works if an element with selector #wmd-input is on the page. So, it would similarly not work if you've already answered (non-self), if there are too many answers already, and anything else that might hide the text area behind a click.

From what VLAZ found this sounds like a bug: "Fix the A shortcut for posts where the text area is not loaded by default"
